# Is there a way to assign variables and values and refer to the new variables in a bash for loop?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to execute a for loop, create new variables with values that vary with the loop iteration, and refer to the new variables within the loop or later in the shell script.
Can't figure out how to refer to the new variables because of the way they are being evaluated.
A simple example of what I need but does not work -

```
for i in {1..4}
 do
 my${i}var="./path_to/my${i}file"
 echo $my${i}var
 done
```

Comment: You can do this I suppose, but why not use an array variable instead? Assign with `myvar[$i]=...` and use with `"${myvar[$i]}"`.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [Bash arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html) for that.

```
for i in 0 1 2 3
do
    myvar[$i]="./path_to/my${i}file"
    echo ${myvar[$i]}
done
```